# plotly scattermapbox : add annotations / text

Tags: python, plotly, mapbox, plotly-dash

I am using plotly scattermapbox to update the map from callback. I'd like to add some annotation / text to the map in a fix position. It's not quite clear from the documentation if this is something that I can use `paper` annotations for as https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/.

```
      layout = {

                 "autosize": True,
                 "hovermode": "closest",
                 "mapbox": {

                     "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                     "bearing": 0,
                     "center": {
                         "lat": layout_lat,
                         "lon": layout_lon
                     },
                     "pitch": 0,
                     "zoom": zoom,
                     "style": "outdoors",

                 },

                 "annotations": {

                     "x": 1,
                     "y": 0,
                     "showarrow":False,
                     "text":'Custom annotation text',
                     "xref":'paper',
                     "yref":'paper'

                 },

                 "margin": {
                    "r": 0,
                    "t": 0,
                    "l": 0,
                    "b": 0,
                    "pad": 0
                }

    }
```

Comment: The layout data you get by adding the following annotations to this [official example](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#basic-example) is the same as the dictionary format you have posted. `fig.add_annotation(x=0.5,y=0.5,xref='paper',yref='paper',text='Custom annotation text',font={'color':'blue','size':18},showarrow=False,yshift=10)`

Comment: The 'paper' is supposed to be based on the plot area and the 'domain' on the axis, but there was no difference on the map; if the coordinates shift on the Dash, you may need to change them to 'domain'.

Comment: @r-beginners I changed `paper` to `domain`, didn't make any difference on the map. For map, what are the axes?

Comment: I've tried both and had no change, so I guess either one is fine.